# admob isnt working because of (I think) google play services

Tags: java, android, admob

I am trying for at least 6h how to ad an admob banner.
The banner is just visible in the grafical view of the activity_main.xml. There it shows blank just the text: Ads by Google.
If I start it on a real device, nothing apear not even a box just nothing and you cant click it.
My LogCat output:

```
01-21 18:59:26.768: I/Ads(26882): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("7DC393B415BE44EB0BBB77E514CE33C3") to get test ads on this device.
01-21 18:59:26.778: I/Ads(26882): Starting ad request.
01-21 18:59:26.898: W/(26882): init htc webcore
01-21 19:00:27.168: W/Ads(26882): Timed out waiting for ad response.
01-21 19:00:27.178: I/Ads(26882): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
01-21 19:00:27.183: W/Ads(26882): Failed to load ad: 2
01-21 19:01:27.208: I/Ads(26882): Starting ad request.
01-21 19:02:27.363: W/Ads(26882): Timed out waiting for ad response.
01-21 19:02:27.413: I/Ads(26882): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
01-21 19:02:27.418: W/Ads(26882): Failed to load ad: 2

01-21 19:01:27.363: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(26882): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

I am sure that I included all the things correct, but if you have any ideas what i have done false just say.

So I hope anyone can help me out with admob.

Answer (score 4):

It's an old post, but who knows, it might help somebody.

**Disable your Ad Blocker**

Yeah the situation is ironic, but it's not the first thing to come in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to the [Google Mobile Ads documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/package-summary.html). Error code 2 (from your log output) indicates the problem with Internet connection: see [ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.html#ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR).

To troubleshoot a problem check [/etc/hosts file](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60150/how-to-edit-etc-hosts-file) and [network connection](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/tip/How-to-troubleshoot-Android-Wi-Fi-connection-problems).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are including Google Play Services library in your project configuration also check if internet connection is working on your device.

Check out official guide on Admob integration for Android https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom ROM?

Try the ad loading on an emulator, some roms tend to block ads by default. I've got experience with exactly the same problem as you are facing (also on an HTC device)

Good luck!